# Dev environment for legacy Visual Studio code?

Tags: docker, windows, virtualization

I work at a small company that has several legacy projects that all require different versions of visual studio to run. The company has servers on site and I have a small cloud budget. I want to set up the projects such that it doesn't matter which visual studio the project is opened it, it should still run the same. The projects are all asp.net, run on IIS, and use SQL Server. I'd like to know where to get started, such as should I try to containerize the applications? Should I set up some sort of VM Image with the projects on it? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... legacy projects that all require different versions of visual studio ...

Don't you just *love* Visual Studio?

> ... I want to set up the projects such that it doesn't matter which visual studio the project is opened ...

If your "legacy" goes back beyond .Net 2, then you're out of luck.

New, shiny versions of Visual Studio won't open .Net 1.* projects and will shrink away *in horror* from anything that needs anything created in 'Studio 6 (except, possibly, C++, the one language that's survived .Net-ification largely unscathed).

Most of the newer stuff will happily co-exist, but you'll probably need to think about  containerising the earlier stuff.